# How should I sum up some values when the corresponding elements appears in the other column?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a DF BV1, and I have a vector BV2. How could I sum up the V(values) of R(regions) from BV1 when the elments show in both BV1 and BV2.

```
BV1 = data.frame(R= c("CHL","EGY","ETH","IND","IRN"), V = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
    R   V
1   CHL 1
2   EGY 2
3   ETH 3
4   IND 4
5   IRN 5    
BV2 = c("CHL","IRN","PPP") # "CHL" and "IRN" show in both BV1 and BV2
CHL+IRN=6 in BV1 #For example, I would like to have this result.
```

As I have 50 regions, it is a quick method to apply for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see `help("[.data.frame")` for details

```
sum(BV1[BV1$R %in% BV2, "V"])
```